# Play! Framework 1.2.4: Is it possible to know parameters of a pending job (doJobWithResult)

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-1.x

i am working on an application that works with an array of async calculations.

heres how the job cerated:

```
    List<F.Promise<PredictionCalculator>> promises = new ArrayList<F.Promise<PredictionCalculator>>();
    predictWithJobResult pj = new predictWithJobResult(parameter).now;
    promises.add(pj)
```

i do this for n number of times, and after adding jobs to the queue, i execure this code:

```
promises.notifyAll();
```

so jobs are starting to run, my problem is, this job is running on every 60mins. so if there is a job already running with "x" parameter, it has to skip adding this job into the queue again.

So my question is, how can i query running jobs and their parameters? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not build a running job queue object (Singleton) which you can query in which jobs check for their paramaters on the queue before running, add themselves while running, and remove themselves when finished.

Comment: that might be a good point, but i am also wondering if we can get what jobs are running with "play status" command, cant we also be able to get that info with code ?

Comment: One thing to be weary of: Play is stateless. If you spin up multiple servers this will pose an issue regarding checking if a job is already running. Unfortunately, a better approach would be adding entries to your DB.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to get the Job from the Promise. What you can do is use a Map,predictWithJobResult> instead of a list to store you promises and use this map to lookup your job from your promise